# Dangerous answers

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

My personal experience:

"How can I do *something* in *some software product*?" someone asked on the Stack Overflow site.

I knew the answer, so I posted it. However, my answer is dangerous, because it reveals a security issue in *some software*. I had not not realized that. Moreover, I probably unintentionally broke a very strict NDA of the vendor of *some software*.

In a few minutes, my answer was accepted and I got many upvotes. In an hour I realized what had happened and I tried to delete my answer but I could not, because the answer had already been accepted. The answer was indexed by Google in the moment I posted it, so deleting would be useless anyway.

What should I have done?

Comment: Interesting.  I looked at one of my accepted answers and it allows me to vote for deletion.

Comment: I need to delete it immeditaly... And I need to be sure that there is no record of my answer on SO site...

Comment: Well, you should not have broken the NDA terms.  There's fairly little to do about it now, no doubt a bunch of vampire sites have copied your post.  Flag a moderator with a custom flag that explains the NDA violation, he might take pity on you and reduce the exposure risk.  Nevertheless, you ought to contact whomever owns the NDA contract and notify them of your oops, always better when you volunteer this then them finding out by themselves.

Comment: _"The answer was indexed by Google in the moment I posted it, so deleting would be useless anyway."_ - Once it's deleted, the search results will disappear shortly after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flag it and explain why it should be deleted to the moderators as you have explained here so eloquently.

Comment: If this is purely an NDA issue, it is not something for the moderators to handle, because the contract is not ours to enforce. Not sure about security implications however.

Comment: But is it not your ability to Delete it if the Poster requests a delete based on a mistake he made?  Allowing him to show he is trying to meet his obligation?

Comment: Ah, I'd missed that the user was asking about their own accepted answer. In that case I would honor their request.

Comment: +1 I am breathing a lot easier knowing that! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As everyone has been saying flag it for moderator attention. If you post the link to that answer ( BTW, I am not asking for the link so that I can misuse your answer as I am not that good at programming ) , we will help you by flagging it as well.

Since you yourself have realized your mistake, **you should edit the answer and remove the problematic part** ( but as @talves said, this only hides it from the front page view, but the edit can be seen, but it will help dealing with the problem temporarily until the answer is deleted ) . That way, some of the problems will be solved.

But it is good of you to have raised this issue. It would have been a lot worse if you had not brought this issue to light.

Also, as @HansPassant said, you should notify the owner of the NDA of this.

Comment: Editing will remove it from front page view, but does not remove it from someone being able to see the edit.  Of course, that would allow it to be somewhat hidden until the moderators delete it permanently.

Comment: @talves , good point. Is it okay if I add that part of your comment to my answer ?

Comment: Sure, I appreciate you asking.

Answer (score 0):

You were certainly not at fault for answering a question to the best of your ability, especially if in the process of answering the question, the harm that the answer might have caused was not apparent to you. Better to be careful, but at any rate, it is not your job to protect careless developers.